# How can I bind Alt+Shift+h to previous window in tmux?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm trying to use tmux (in xterm) in a vim friendly way. This is my .tmux.conf right now.

```
bind-key -n M-Down    select-pane -D
bind-key -n M-Up      select-pane -U
bind-key -n M-Left    select-pane -L
bind-key -n M-Right   select-pane -R

bind-key -n M-j       select-pane -D
bind-key -n M-k       select-pane -U
bind-key -n M-l       select-pane -L
bind-key -n M-h       select-pane -R

bind-key -n S-M-Right next-window
bind-key -n S-M-Left  previous-window
bind-key -n S-M-Up    split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind-key -n S-M-Down  split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"

// these do not work
bind-key -n S-M-l     next-window
bind-key -n S-M-h     previous-window
bind-key -n S-M-k     split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind-key -n S-M-j     split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

The last four lines do not work and those shortcuts do not do anything else in either tmux or vim. Is there a reason that they don't work or are they bound to some global shortcut that I can't find?

Comment: There is no `S` (Shift) in the keybinds: use the uppercase variant of the letter.

Comment: That worked. Although `S` works with the arrow keys so it does stand for `Shift` there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`S-l` is `L`, so you should be binding `M-L` instead of `S-M-l`, and similarly for the other bindings.